# AWS Lambda module initialization error

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I have recently started Lambda function development on AWS. When try to import a JavaScript file I am getting the following error,

```
module initialization error: ReferenceError
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/model/claim_type.js:3:29)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:2:19)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

In root level I have the *index.js* file and *claim_type.js* file inside the *model* directory.

index.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const ClaimType = require('./model/claim_type.js');

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    //function content
}
```

claim_type.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const ClaimType = sequelize.define('claimtype', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
}, {
        timestamps: false
    });

module.exports = ClaimType;
```

What is the correct way to import the *claim_type.js*?

Comment: It looks like sequelize isn't found. Are you deploying the node_modules directory with you own sources to lamdba?

Comment: yes, I am using the command *zip -r Lambda-Deployment.zip * -x *.zip *.json *.log* to create the zip file. I think it's not related to the sequelize because it was working fine until I moved the *ClaimType* to a separate file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const ClaimType = sequelize.define('claimtype', {
```

your const is Camelcase, but the second line is lowercase!